# Debugging a Program for Grading Students With String Split into Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble debugging the following code so that the input is 4 people and 4 separate grades with spaces in between that returns the student's grade based on the highest score, but I continuously get an error. Somebody please help. Thank You!

Output:

```
Enter the number of students: 4 
Enter 4 scores: 55 48 70 58 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
     Index 4 out of bounds for length 4 at Ex7_1.main(Ex7_1.java:15)
```

```
import java.util.*;
public class Ex7_1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of students: ");

    int num = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()) + 1;
    System.out.printf("Enter %d scores: ", 4);

    String input = in.nextLine();
    String[] sArray = input.split(" ");
    int[] array = new int[num];

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      String sNum = sArray[i];
      array[i] = Integer.parseInt(sNum);
    }

    int highest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
      if (array[i] >= highest) {
        highest = array[i];
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
      int score = array[i];
      if (score >= (highest - 10)) {
        System.out.printf("Student %d score is %d and grade is A", i, score);
      } else if (score >= (highest - 20)) {
        System.out.printf("Student %d score is %d and grade is B", i, score);
      } else if (score >= (highest - 30)) {
        System.out.printf("Student %d score is %d and grade is C", i, score);
      } else if (score >= (highest - 40)) {
        System.out.printf("Student %d score is %d and grade is D", i, score);
      } else {
        System.out.printf("Student %d score is %d and grade is F", i, score);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code presents an error after making the <= to just < in both cases. I do not know how to solve that error. Please help. Thank You!

Comment: What error? Please provide an [MCVE]

Comment: Enter the number of students:
4
Enter 4 scores: 55 48 70 58
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4

        at Ex7_1.main(Ex7_1.java:15)

Comment: How would I solve this problem?

Comment: That did solve one problem, but after I fix that problem, another one arises that I can't seem to fix, this is the error: Enter the number of students:
48 55 70 58
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "48 55 70 58"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)

        at Ex7_1.main(Ex7_1.java:7)

Comment: How would I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: `int num = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()) + 1;` looks weird. I guess you are trying to get the number of input scores? If that is the case, you can use `int num = sArray.length;` after `String[] sArray = input.split(" ");` And, in java, for an array of length 4, the index are 0, 1, 2 and 3, so you should use < instead of <=

Comment: Thank you but how do I solve the error in the previous comment

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you need to enter the number of students. Could you please change line 7 into the following three lines: first line: `String numStr = in.nextLine();` , second line: `System.out.println(numStr);` , third line: `int num = Integer.parseInt(numStr) + 1;`, and reproduce the error. Tell me what is printed out in the console.

Comment: According to the error message, it seems that you typed "48 55 70 58" for "Enter the number of students:", so you just forgot to type 4 (meaning 4 students) before input their scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `<=` operator in every `for loop`. In beginning, almost everybody get confused in this part **Arrays start with 0 index**. So you don't have to use `>=`, use this instead `>` in your `for loops`.

Secondly, if your always entering marks of 4 students, then don't ask this:

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of students: ");
```

What if user input "5". Your will go like:

```
Enter the number of students: 5
Enter 4 scores:
```

So, this doesn't make a good sense. At last put a `\n` in your printing segment of the code, it'll make the output more clearer and easy to read:

```
System.out.printf("\nStudent %d score is %d and grade is A", i, score); // "\n" added
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem isn't in either of the sections where you look through the array, but rather where you set the contents of the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  String sNum = sArray[i];
  array[i] = Integer.parseInt(sNum);
}
```

It seems that in this section, you try to access the item at index 4 of `sArray`, which does not exist, as the array has a length of 4, and thus a maximum index of 3.

Additionally, you are adding 1 to num near the beginning, which isn't necessary if you use `<` instead of `<=` in the for-loops, and is causing you to use indexes 1 through 4, instead of 0 through 3 as you likely want.

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()) + 1; // You don't need this +1
```

Finally, that print statement where you ask for a number of scores will always print out 4, no matter how many you actually need. You likely want to pass `num` into that print statement, so it actually prints out how many scores you're expecting.

```
System.out.printf("Enter %d scores: ", 4); // Replace this 4 with num
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException :-

int num = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()) + 1; //remove + 1 from this line
use < instead of <= in the for-loops

To avoid NumberFormatException :-

Trim your string and while splitting use regex which matches any number of whitespace characters.
\\s+ - matches sequence of one or more whitespace characters.

Try below code:

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of students: ");

        int num = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.printf("Enter %d scores: ", num);

        String input = in.nextLine().trim();
        String[] sArray = input.split("\\s+");
        int[] array = new int[num];

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            String sNum = sArray[i];
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(sNum);
        }

        int highest = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (array[i] >= highest) {
                highest = array[i];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            int score = array[i];
            if (score >= (highest - 10)) {
                System.out.printf("Student %d score is %d and grade is A\n", i+1, score);
            } else if (score >= (highest - 20)) {
                System.out.printf("Student %d score is %d and grade is B\n", i+1, score);
            } else if (score >= (highest - 30)) {
                System.out.printf("Student %d score is %d and grade is C\n", i+1, score);
            } else if (score >= (highest - 40)) {
                System.out.printf("Student %d score is %d and grade is D\n", i+1, score);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("Student %d score is %d and grade is F\n", i+1, score);
            }
        }
    }
```